# Can I have an additional functions.php file in Wordpress?

Tags: functions, include

There're quite a lot of functions, and so, does my theme, it all gets a little cluttered even with all the comments. Additionally, every time the theme is updated, the new functions.php file would replace the current one.

So, it becomes a pain.

Hence, I thought, would it be possible to have a 2nd/3rd functions.php file? Using PHP include or require function. That way, I can categorise the functions and they won't be affected on theme update.

So,

```
<?php include 'functions_1.php' ?>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Are you using a [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/)?

Comment: @Milo No child theme used

Comment: If you want to add functionality to a theme modifying it in any way (even just to include other files) is not the way to do it. This is what child themes are for.

Comment: yes, you can include other files. it's just like any other php file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rid of the theme update situation by using a child theme. Your child theme will work as an extension of the parent theme that you update often. You can learn more about child theme from [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).

But if you don't wanna use child theme then yes, you can add as many additional functions file as you want. A regular `include` or `require` will just work fine. You can include file using a relative path or you can use [`get_template_directory()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory) function for an absolute path. For instance

```
include get_template_directory() . '/inc/functions-1.php'; // if it's inside inc directory
include get_template_directory() . '/functions-1.php'; // Or if it's not inside any directory
```